# Нужно лы создавать новый компонент в цикле React

Tags: reactjs

Например мы хотим вывести телефонную книгу

```
Роман - 123
Иван - 487
 ... 
Тарас - 034
```

Вопрос в том как лучше делать: все в одном компоненте ContactList

```
function ContactList (props) {
   return (
     <div>
       {props.contacts.map (item => <div> {item.name} - {item.phone} </ div>)}
      </ div>
   )
}
```

или разбивать ещё на ContactListItem компонент:

```
function ContactList (props) {
   return (
     <div>
       {props.contacts.map (item => <ContactListItem key = {item.id} name = {item.name} phone = {item.phone} />)}
      </ div>
   )
}

function ContactListItem (props) {
   return (
     <div>
       {props.name} - {props.phone} </ div>
      </ div>
   )
}
```

и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Если вам надо вывести просто список, то достаточно первого варианта.

Если же с каждой строчкой должны происходить отдельные действия (редактирование, обновление, событие по клику и т.д.) то лучше создать ContactListItem, где будет реализован весь функционал работы с отдельным контактом, а в ContactList вывести список ContactListItem'ов